# Pandas: How to apply a value to a group of rows based on a specific row value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, where I want to recreate the column `To Show?`. The idea is if the Product group has a value of `Red` in the `Color` column of any row then I want the `To Show?` column with the value `Yes` for all the rows of `Product A`. For any Product group that does not have the value as `Red`, I want the value to be `No` for that column.

```
   Year  Week Product   Color To Show?
0  2019    21       A   Green      Yes
1  2019    22       A   Green      Yes
2  2019    23       A     Red      Yes
3  2019    24       A   Green      Yes
4  2019    25       C   Green       No
5  2019    26       C  Yellow       No
6  2019    27       C   Green       No
7  2019    28       B   Green      Yes
8  2019    29       B     Red      Yes
9  2019    30       B  Yellow      Yes
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019],
    'Week': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    'Product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Color': ['Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Green', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow'],
    'To Show?': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have tried using unique, but not sure how to parse the Series and assign value based on that?

```
df1 = df.groupby('Product')['Color'].unique()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` to broadcast results and `map` to make them `Yes/No`

```
df['To Show?'] = df.groupby('Product').Color\
                                      .transform(lambda x: x.eq('Red').any())\
                                      .map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Comment: What is `.eq`?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @Trenton_M It works the same as `==` in this case :) I just find it easier to read than having `(x == 'Red').any()`, but that's a personal preference. The main difference between `==` and `.eq` is the possibility to state a `fill_value` argument when using the latter, which can be useful ;). If you wanna know more, may take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

Comment: Okay, so it's the `pandas` implementation of [Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html)...which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3):

We can `Groupby.transform` with `any` (if any of the rows in the group is Red) and `np.where` for conditional creation of our new column:

```
m = df.groupby('Product')['Color'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('Red').any())

df['To Show?'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')
```

**Output**

```
   Year  Week Product   Color To Show?
0  2019    21       A   Green      Yes
1  2019    22       A   Green      Yes
2  2019    23       A     Red      Yes
3  2019    24       A   Green      Yes
4  2019    25       C   Green       No
5  2019    26       C  Yellow       No
6  2019    27       C   Green       No
7  2019    28       B   Green      Yes
8  2019    29       B     Red      Yes
9  2019    30       B  Yellow      Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `where` to flip any `non-'Red'` of `df.Color` to `NaN` and groupby `df.product`; then, `transform` with `first` and `replace`

```
df['To Show?'] =  (df.Color.where(df.Color.eq('Red'))
                           .groupby(df.Product)
                           .transform('first') 
                           .replace(['Red', np.nan], ['Yes', 'No']))

Out[364]:
   Year  Week Product   Color To Show?
0  2019    21       A   Green      Yes
1  2019    22       A   Green      Yes
2  2019    23       A     Red      Yes
3  2019    24       A   Green      Yes
4  2019    25       C   Green       No
5  2019    26       C  Yellow       No
6  2019    27       C   Green       No
7  2019    28       B   Green      Yes
8  2019    29       B     Red      Yes
9  2019    30       B  Yellow      Yes
```

---

Or you may use `map` with the dictionary create from the mask of `Product` and `Color` and map this dict to `Product` and `replace`

```
d = dict(df.loc[df.Color.eq('Red'), ['Product', 'Color']].values)

Out[375]: {'A': 'Red', 'B': 'Red'}

df['To Show?'] = df.Product.map(d).replace(['Red', np.nan], ['Yes', 'No'])

Out[379]:
   Year  Week Product   Color To Show?
0  2019    21       A   Green      Yes
1  2019    22       A   Green      Yes
2  2019    23       A     Red      Yes
3  2019    24       A   Green      Yes
4  2019    25       C   Green       No
5  2019    26       C  Yellow       No
6  2019    27       C   Green       No
7  2019    28       B   Green      Yes
8  2019    29       B     Red      Yes
9  2019    30       B  Yellow      Yes
```